# Flutter, Temporizador en segundo plano

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart, iphone

quisiera saber si alguno me pudiera ayudar con algo que intento hacer.

Estoy creando un temporizador que avance, pero donde quedo es en dejarlo persistente en el dispositivo, es decir que si cierro la App siga funcionando sin perder su valor, ¿Esto es válido?.¿Funcionara en segundo plano?.
Sí, estoy tratando de hacer un reloj
**sin usar hora del dispositivo**, para usarlo en una App de registro de asistencia.

Agradezco el tiempo de cada uno, Gracias... Saludos

Hasta el momento encontré lo siguiente:

````
class RelojInterno extends StatefulWidget {
  const RelojInterno({super.key});

  @override
  State<RelojInterno> createState() => _RelojInternoState();
}

class _RelojInternoState extends State<RelojInterno> {
  Duration duration = const Duration();
  Timer? timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    startTimer(); // Inicio Reloj
  }

  void addTime() {
    const addSecond = 1;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(
        () {
          final seconds = duration.inSeconds + addSecond;
          duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
        },
      );
    }
  }

  void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => addTime());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');

    final hours = twoDigits(duration.inHours);
    final minute = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    final seconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return Text(
      '$hours:$minute:$seconds',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: HexColor('#11cdef'), //Celeste
      ),
    );
  }
} ```
````

Comment: hola Jorge, deberías ver los background services y foreground services. tal vez ya haya algún package/plugin para flutter y no tengas que ir a nativo directamente. De todas formas, no podes garantizar que tu servicio de segundo plano vaya a correr indefinidamente. depende de la config del user con el celu, batería, os

Comment: Gracias... Buen punto lo de nativo, no tengo mucha experiencia pero también podría buscar como implementarlo, le echare un vistazo, Gracias nuevamente